# How to iterate through a series of prompted inputs up to a specific number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, command-prompt

I'm trying to make a simple function in `javascript` that takes in a numerical prompt input. Stores it. And once the Sum of all input number is equal or greater to 50, for the prompt to quit and for a `console.log` to show the amount of numbers typed in and the total sum.

This is the HTML code that links my JS file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ex6 JS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ex6.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Exercise 6 JS</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

```
var my_array = [];
var sum=0; 

var num_infinito = parseInt(prompt('Introduzca todos sus numeros'));

my_array.push(num_infinito);

if(my_array >= 50){
    cantidadNumeros();
    sumaNumeros();
}else{
    obtenerMasNumeros();
}

function obtenerMasNumeros(){

    var num_infinito = parseInt(prompt('Introduzca todos sus numeros'));
    my_array.push(num_infinito);

    for (var i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++) {

        sum += my_array[i++];

        if (sum>50) {
            cantidadNumeros();
            sumaNumeros();

        } else if (sum<50){
            var num_infinito = parseInt(prompt('Introduzca todos sus numeros'));
            my_array.push(num_infinito);

        } else {
            cantidadNumeros();
            sumaNumeros();
        }
    }
}

function cantidadNumeros(){
    //var my_arrayIndex = my_array.length; 
    console.log('Has ingresado '+ String(my_array.length) + ' numeros');
}

function sumaNumeros(){
    console.log('La suma de los numeros ingresados es ' + String(sum));
}
```

The output for this code so far is:

A prompt asking me to input a number. If number >= 50 it stops, but if number <= 50 (lets say I input 40) it enters the function. Once it enters the function I will type 50, but instead of stopping in the first "if" statement it goes straight to the "else if" statemente. So: I am prompted to input another number, 40.

After inputting 40 the output is:

`Has ingresado 3 numeros`
`La suma de los numeros ingresados es 80`

So, for some reason the second 50 is ignored and it skips straight to the third input number (40) and adds that to the first input number.

**SECONDLY**

if I am prompted to type and I type [1], and then go on to type 2 and then 3 and then 4, the function stops at 4 and returns an array with 4 numbers (1, 2, 3, 4) but withought any output

**THIRDLY**

Say, 40 is the first input, then, 10 then 10. the output is:

```
total sum = 50 and my_array[3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some pretty thorough comments to explain the flow. I've also shown you what you should do when you're checking against a single value (scope it and access the var). That way, you can change the threshold by changing one number. Makes testing *WAY* easier. Try for yourself!

You had some conflicts with how you were arranging and firing your code. I've added some comments to hopefully show you how to set up conditional flow. Let me know if you have any more questions about the code that I can help you with. :)

```js
var my_array = [];
// initial states are cleared on document load
var sum=0;
var thresh=50;

// This initially gets the obtener loop started by feeding it a number to start with
var num_infinito = parseInt(prompt('Introduzca todos sus numeros'));

my_array.push(num_infinito);

if(my_array >= thresh){
    // There will only be one value on start, so we don't need to loop here. Sum is the only value, index[0]
    sum = my_array[0];
    // Show values and run final function
    cantidadNumeros();
    sumaNumeros();
}else{
    // If value does not exceed the threshold, continue with running the function
    obtenerMasNumeros();
}

function obtenerMasNumeros(){
    // Grabbing another value
    var num_infinito = parseInt(prompt('Introduzca todos sus numeros'));
    // Add it to array
    my_array.push(num_infinito);
    // Re-init sum to go through the entire array
    sum = 0;
    var exceed = false; // We want to go through array no matter what
    for (var i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++) 
    {     
      // Where we add the sum (first time is 0 + my_array[i])
      sum += my_array[i];
      if (sum >= thresh)
      {
        // If we exceed 50, we want to set the flag
        exceed = true;
      }
    }
    // We've iterated and gotten the sum. Now we check if it's exceeded the threshold or not
    
    if ( exceed )
    {
        // Threshold is broken, run final sequence and return
        cantidadNumeros();
        sumaNumeros();
        return;
        // We return here to avoid the code below from running
    }
    obtenerMasNumeros();
}

function cantidadNumeros(){
    console.log('Has ingresado '+ my_array.length + ' numeros');
}

function sumaNumeros(){
    console.log('La suma de los numeros ingresados es ' + String(sum));
}
```

Comment: Hello Joel, your code works perfectly but I have some questions:

Firstly, if i take sum = 0 from ObtenerMasNumeros(), the code breaks and will register only 3 numbers into the array and break. Why is it important to call sum = 0 again?

Secondly, in sum  += my_array[i], why did you take out i++? I dont think i understand the difference between the two.

Thridly, How is it that calling obtenerMasNumeros() inside of itself doesnt cause an error but a "while loop". When I tried using while loops my program would just show the prompt but your method works perfectly

Comment: Every time you iterate over the array again, you want to re-initialize sum. Otherwise, you're taking values outside of that loop. You are only scoping `sum` outside of the function so that other functions can access it. You can also just use sum as a parameter of `sumaNumeros(sum) {}` and just pass it the value to avoid globals.

Comment: i++ is an incrementor, and if there isn't a value *after* `i`, it's going to break, as there isn't an 8th index [(i=7)+1] of your array if it's 7 long. This way, you're iterating over the entire array, and just breaking the for loop when it finishes or exceeds the sum.

Comment: I went through the code and added a different route to *always* add the sum per your final function (I missed that part). I also added a ton of comments to explain each step. Hopefully that clears it up for you!